# Error Lua compilation error: [string "CHILD SCRIPT LBR_iiwa_7_R800#0"]:14: '' expected near 'end'

Tags: lua

I have no idea what is generating the error:    Error
Lua compilation error: [string "CHILD SCRIPT LBR_iiwa_7_R800#0"]:14: '' expected near 'end'

""
function sysCall_init()

```
--Initializations
    
RefPosition=sim.getObjectHandle("Target")
EndEffector=sim.getObjectHandle("Tip")

Connector= sim.getObjectHandle("Connector")
Proximity=sim.getObjectHandle("Proximity")

Chevy_ChargerPOS=sim.getObjectPosition(Chevy_Charger,-1)

end
end

function sysCall_actuation()
    t=sim.getSimulationTime()
    if(t>=10) then do
    sim.setObjectPosition(Target,-1,Chevy_ChargerPOS) -- move reference to pick position
end

end
```

""

Comment: Move the first `end` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have four 'end' statements. You only should have three. Remove the first one per the comment below

```
function sysCall_init() 
        --Initializations
            
        RefPosition=sim.getObjectHandle("Target")
        EndEffector=sim.getObjectHandle("Tip")
        
        Connector= sim.getObjectHandle("Connector")
        Proximity=sim.getObjectHandle("Proximity")
        
        Chevy_ChargerPOS=sim.getObjectPosition(Chevy_Charger,-1)
    
    -- REMOVED end
        
        function sysCall_actuation()
            t=sim.getSimulationTime()
            if (t>=10) then do
                sim.setObjectPosition(Target,-1,Chevy_ChargerPOS) -- move reference to pick position
            end — end for if statement 
        
        end — end for internal function declaration
    end — end of outer function definition
```